# Modifying my SQL 2008 SSIS Package from C# renders the modification invisible

Tags: ssis

I have a small solution that i provide to several people. The solution consists of amongst other things an existing SsisPackage (default.dtsx). I modify this according to some settings in my application to prepare it for transfering data from a datasource to a datamart. I add a sequence container, add a foreachloop and add a dadtaflowtask. Each of these are added (i know i can see them in the package explorer) and the package can execute without problems.

My problem is that when i look at my package i cannot see the elements i added, they are invisible, they exist in the xmla and are visible in the package. Anyone got a possible solution for this - it makes the package almost impossible to maintain for the receiving developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT / SOLUTION:** For posterity i will document my findings :-)

I have been conparing the underlying xml structure to find this solution so here it comes. The problem is due to the fact that im modifying an already created package. When the package was first made in BIDS layout information was saved within a xml tag called <packagevariable> - all elements have their layout written in encoded xml in the xmla file.

When i go and modify the package through C# and add new elements the layout information is not updated! So when the package is loaded within the BIDS for modification the BIDS recognizes that some layout information is available, so it will use this information to layout the ENTIRE PACKAGE. This means that while we have no layout information for the elements we have added, they are not layed out.

My next step will be to investigate into removing the layout information - then the package will layout the package in a default manner. I will investigate into how to remove it using the API (first priority) else i will have to open the file at XML/Text and make a manual removal (hopefully i will avoid this).

Enjoy!